# Error while upgrading from .net core 2.1 to .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have a solution that contains my API Project and my Test Project. We are now upgrading from .net core 2.1 to 3.1

So first I did edited my project file of API and updated from netcoreapp2.1 to netcoreapp3.1. I then updated all my nuget packages to latest versions and rebuild my API project and it was all fine.

Then I did the same for my TEST project but it gave me lot of nuget errors and even when I try to upgrade each package one by one, it doesnt let me do it and keeps giving errors. Below is my Test project file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Core" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Logging.AspNetCore" Version="2.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json" Version="1.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.TestUtilities" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.Core" Version="3.3.103.32" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.13.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NBuilder" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenCover" Version="4.6.519" />
    <PackageReference Include="ReportGenerator" Version="3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="TimeZoneConverter" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.1.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
<PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DATA\DATA.API.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>


<!--
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="netstandard">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\netstandard.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
-->
</Project>
```

I keep getting below errors:

[image]

Any inputs on how to get it resolved. Thanks

Comment: "even when I try to upgrade each package one by one, it doesnt let me do it and keeps giving errors" - *those* errors would be good to know. For example, it looks like you should update your direct NBuilder dependency to 6.1.0 - or remove the direct dependency entirely. You may well find that you can remove *lots* of your direct dependencies, due to the indirect ones.

Comment: Try changing the version numbers in your *.csproj files, to the new versions. Sometimes nuget shows these errors while it's in the progress of updating packages. Starting with the Microsoft.* packages, since they are still on version 2.1.1

Comment: Looks like it was dependencies issues with each other when I was trying to update them individually. I selected upgrade all and it upgrade all the packages. Now its not giving any package issue but its giving me error here using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal: The type or namespace name 'Internal' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http' AND in this line  DefaultHttpRequest defaultHttpRequest : The type or namespace name 'DefaultHttpRequest' could not be found

Comment: I can create a separate issue for error I am getting now